# Assigning permissions based on taxonomies

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a hierarchical taxonomy that looks like this:

School>Class>Project

That is you could have a project that is part of a certain class that is part of a certain school.  I would like to make it so that only students that are enrolled in a specific class can submit content to that class/project.  Also, I would like to have a semi-adminstrator role called teacher that can only enroll students into a class that they are administering but cannot enroll students into other classes.

I have found a depreciated module called taxonomy based permissions but it seems like it was abandoned after drupal 5 (I am using drupal 7).  Are there any new modules that might help me accomplish these goals?  If not, this problem seems a little bit outside of the intended functionality of taxonomies, I am wondering if I am using the wrong kind  of model for my site.  Any feedback on this though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) sounds like a better way to go in this situation. Each class is a group (can still categorize them using taxonomy), but will give you the sub-permissions you require per class (group) (e.g. teacher being able to enroll and administer their own group and students only being able to submit content in their own class)

OG enables users to create and manage their own 'groups'. Each group can have subscribers, and maintains a group home page where subscribers communicate amongst themselves.

They do so by posting the usual node types: blog, story, page, etc. A block is shown on the group home page which facilitates these posts. The block also provides summary information about the group.

Groups may be selective or not. Selective groups require approval in order to become a member, or even invitation -only groups. There are lots of preferences to configure groups as you need.